# Unable to do remote session

Tags: remote, session

Im having problem when remoting my linux mint server.  I tried teamviewer and anydesk but i cant connect i already change my router but still i,  cant connect any reason why its happening.. I tried to ssh usong putty but no avail  , i also try to access them by filemanger using php still i can view the record but cant do anything
   Does anyone knows whats happening or does my os is the culprit

Comment: There really isn't any useful info in your post that could point to the specific problem, so the only thing to do is guess at any number of possible causes. Are you trying to ssh from an external network? If so, is port forwarding setup on your router? Does Mint have a firewall on it and if so are the proper exceptions in place? Is the ssh service enabled on Mint? In Teamviewer is it setup to allow remote access into it or is it only setup to allow connections out of it?

Comment: The port forwarding is enable slso thw ssh..  Ill check the firewall but all remote access spplication cant be open in the browser